# What software do mining pools run?

Tags: mining-pools, mining-software

I assume they run bitcoind for the network connectivity.  But what about for the work allocation?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are several pool-implementations that create the individual workloads and track their completion. The [Poolservers](https://en.bitcoin.it/wiki/Poolservers) article at the bitcoin.it Wiki has a comprehensive list, with a feature comparison.

Comment: Will these also work for `litecoin`?